# Using sed to replace strings containing special characters

Tags: sed

I'm trying to edit some fastq files.

Essentially I want to change:

```
@SRX1409044.10.1 10 length=80
```

to:

```
@SRX1409044.10/1 10 length=80
```

for every line that contains `.1` in the file.

I've tried using sed:

```
sed 's#.1#/1#g'
```

It works for most lines, however for lines such as:

```
@SRX1409044.11.1 11 length=80
```

I get:

```
@SRX1409044./1/1 /1 length=80
```

I've had a search around and I think I may have to escape the special characters? Every post I came across only gave examples for swapping special characters on their own so I'm not too sure how to go about it.

Comment: `sed 's#\.1 #/1 #g'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command changes the first occurrence of `.1`  (a dot followed by a `1` and a space) on each line to `/1`  – notice the escaped `.`:

```
sed 's|\.1 |/1 |' infile
```

For an example input file such as

```
@SRX1409044.10.1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.12.1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.14.1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.15.1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.990.1 10 length=80
```

the result is

```
@SRX1409044.10/1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.12/1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.14/1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.15/1 10 length=80
@SRX1409044.990/1 10 length=80
```

Now, if the `.1` could also be at the end of a line, we have to change the command slightly because we require a space at the moment:

```
sed 's#\.1\( \|$\)#/1\1#' infile
```

This is "`.1` followed by either a space or the end of the line, replace with `/1` and whatever came after the `.1`". For example:

```
$ sed 's#\.1\( \|$\)#/1\1#' <<< 'SRX1409044.116884523.1'
SRX1409044.116884523/1
```

Answer (score 0):

The decimal point   `.`  is escaped as  `\.`

I think your problem is you need to distinguish single digits and double digits.

If you are not having more than 2 digits the simplest is to repeat the regexp twice, like:

```
[0-9][0-9]
```

Matches any 2 digit number or digit sequence.

- since I don't know which version of  **sed** you are using, and what its enhanced abilities are.

Also I'm not sure what you want to accept, and what you want to reject.

Comment: The file goes from
`SRX1409044.1.1` to `SRX1409044.116884523.1` The only change I would like sed to make is changing .1 at the end to /1.

I'm using sed version 4.2.2 (GNU sed).